# Alocação de memoria vetor de int dentro de uma struct

Tags: c

As minhas estruturas estão definidas desta forma:

```
typedef struct{
    Medicoes *medi;
    unsigned int numeroMots;//comprimento de mots diferentes, nao repete
    int *mots;//MOTS existentes na room
    int compMots;//omprimento do vetor MOTS, pode ter mots iguais
    char **ActuadorName;
    unsigned int countActuador;
    unsigned int *ActuadorOnOff;// 1 se tiver on, 0 se tiver off. Segue o mesmo indice que actuadorName
} Sensores;

typedef struct{
    Sensores *roomName;
    unsigned int countRoom;

} Room;
```

Ao fazer a alocação de memoria recebo um aviso de "Cannot find bounds of current function" 
A minha alocação está da seguinte forma, em que está num ciclo `for`:

```
room->roomName[i].mots=NULL;
room->roomName[i].mots= realloc(room->roomName[i].mots, sizeof(int *) * (vec->elementos[i].CountMots));
```

Está tudo bem definido, `vec->elementos[i].CountMots` contem o numero 3 como por exemplo, ja verifiquei tudo no modo debug e recebe os valores corretos.

A alocaçao está feita de modo correta? Alguem tem uma ideia do que se passa?

Comment: roomName é apenas um ponteiro para uma estrutura Sensores. Você precisa apontar este ponteiro para uma área de memória antes de utiliza-lo (de preferência para uma área que comporte uma estrutura do tipo Sensores).

Comment: Se usar o meu codigo como exemplo para resposta seria muito bom, porque estou tendo dificuldade nisso

Comment: cole aqui as linhas de erro que foram mostradas...deve ter mais informação lá...inclusive porque a mensagem que você colocou aqui não parece fazer sentido: "Cannot find bounds of current function"

Comment: Quando eu corro o programa nao dá erro, apenas dá esse erro quando faço debug do programa.
Nao é um erro ou aviso de compilação, apenas nao me deixa avançar no debug e dá esse aviso

Comment: com as informações postadas acho que não dá pra saber o que está causando o problema...no Stackoverflow em inglês no entanto existem perguntas sobre o assunto: [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8741493/why-i-do-get-cannot-find-bound-of-current-function-when-i-overwrite-the-ret-ad) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420813/using-gdb-to-single-step-assembly-code-outside-specified-executable-causes-error) por exemplo, talvez possam ajudar

Comment: Pois eu compreendo, vou fechar a pergunta.
Queria saber se a alocação estaria correta, era mais isso.